# Socket.io works on localhost but not webserver

Tags: socket.io, webserver

I'm new to socket.io and have been able to get many examples from different tutorials working correctly on my localhost. Now I need help getting it to work on my website. I've been browsing support forms for days with no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Here is what I've done so far...

I exported the code (which was working on my localhost) to my web server (hosted by https://ifastnet.com/) using FileZilla FTP Client and did the same "npm init", "npm install express --save", "npm install socket.io --save", "node app.js" procedure on putty SSH that I used on my CMD when I was able to get it to work on my localhost.

When I go to my website I keep getting "net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" in the browser console (google chrome) when I use

```
var socket = io.connect('http://31.22.4.6:1122');
```

on the client side.

I get "404 (Not Found)" in the browser console when I use

```
var socket = io();
```

I've tried many solutions with no luck

My code is below. Thanks in advance for the help.

server

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen();
// server.listen(1122, "31.22.4.6");

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});

console.log("server started");


io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("connection made");
    socket.emit('news', {
        hello: 'world'
    });
    socket.on('my other event', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

client

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>
  // var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  // var socket = io.connect('http://31.22.4.6:1122');
  var socket = io();
  // var socket = io.connect();
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I suppose that you have followed [these instructions](http://kb.ifastnet.com/index.php?/article/AA-00416/52/Node.js/Using-Node.js-on-a-premium-shared-hosting-account.html)? In this case, just use the default port (80) in the client:  `var socket = io('http://31.22.4.6')` (port 80 is implicit). And uncomment `server.listen(1122, "31.22.4.6")` in the server.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Xodrow. I tried that, but I'm still getting the "net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" error in the console of my browser.

Comment: I once encountered this problem, check my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/76829174/12008648

Answer (score 0):

Are you using https://ifastnet.com.  It doesn't appear that you have access to run node on their servers nor do you have access to serve content on port 1122.

You'll need a service that provides you with ssh, something like Amazon.  They have a free-tier service for you to try out a Ubuntu virtual machine for a few months if you want to try before you buy.

Comment: Yes I am using ifastnet. They did provide me with SSH. I can log in using putty (port 1122) and my credentials. From there I'm able to to start the node using the "node app.js" command. When I run that, I can get messages printed to the putty command line. ex. if you look at my server code above, I see "server started" on the command line when I run "node app.js".