# socket.io works on local network but not when deployed on a vps server

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio, python-socketio

I am creating an interface for a Random Number Generator. Just using the script on my machine, it works perfectly.
But when I host the interface on a Server (IONOS VPS), it does not work properly. I can still access the interface and load the the html. Sometimes it shows one emitted number or 2 and when I still wait sometimes the interface receives another number.

In my python-console I get the periodic GET requests to /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=00maxxx.

This is what my Browser-network-console shows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRpMI.png)

I guess that the connection never really happens completely.
I have already checked the compatibility of flask-socketio with my server.

My server code looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from flask_cors import CORS
import eventlet
import threading

eventlet.monkey_patch()

async_mode = None

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='async_mode', logger=True)

# starting background thread
def background_thread():
    while True:
        socketio.emit('my_response',
                      {'data': 'Server generated event'})

# create html template
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', async_mode=socketio.async_mode)

@socketio.event
def my_ping():
    emit('my_pong')

<... more vent handlers etc. ...>

if __name__ == '__main__':


    PORT = json.load(open('config.json'))["PORT"]
    print("Running on localhost:"+str(PORT))

    socketio.run(app, debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=PORT)
```

The client looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!--Used character set -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Random Number Generator</title>

    <script charset="utf-8" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.min.js') }}">
    <script charset="utf-8" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/socket.io.js') }}"></script>
    <script charset="utf-8" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/server.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>

    
</head>

<body>
    More HTML here
</body>

</html>
```

My server.js looks like this

```
var socket = io();

$(document).ready(function() {

some code 

});

// Interval function that tests message latency by sending a "ping"
    // message. The server then responds with a "pong" message and the
    // round trip time is measured.
    var ping_pong_times = [];
    var start_time;
    window.setInterval(function() {
        start_time = (new Date).getTime();
        $('#transport').text(socket.io.engine.transport.name);
        socket.emit('my_ping');
    }, 1000);

    // Handler for the "pong" message. When the pong is received, the
    // time from the ping is stored, and the average of the last 30
    // samples is average and displayed.
    socket.on('my_pong', function() {
    var latency = (new Date).getTime() - start_time;
    ping_pong_times.push(latency);
    ping_pong_times = ping_pong_times.slice(-30); // keep last 30 samples
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < ping_pong_times.length; i++)
        sum += ping_pong_times[i];
        $('#ping-pong').text(Math.round(10 * sum / ping_pong_times.length) / 10);
    });
```

Anyone has an idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Your connection probably never upgrades to websockets. If that's the case it stays in polling mode and will poll every 25 seconds. [More info on the ping interval](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=ping_interval)

However, I also see you're using `eventlet` and monkey patching it, but you set your `async_mode` to the string `'async_mode'` instead of the value None you define a bit higher. I would try setting it to `'eventlet'`, see if that fixes it.
Like this:

```
import eventlet
import threading
eventlet.monkey_patch()

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='eventlet', logger=True)
```

Also if you're using the development webserver, you might need to use Gunicorn. [Socketio deployment with Gunicorn](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html#gunicorn-web-server)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem of a case where everything worked fine on my localhost but got no websocket connection when i moved the socket.io (expressjs) application to VPS

i had setup virtualhost for different subdomain for my application earlier, and the route for my chatserver was messenger.example.com

All API route in messenger.example.com worked fine except the websocket connection as stated earlier.

I changed my virtualhost content in `/etc/httpd/sites-available/messenger.example.com.conf` to the following.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin sample@gmail.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/messenger.example.com
ServerName messenger.example.com
ErrorLog /var/www/messenger.example.com/error_log
CustomLog /var/www/messenger.example.com/access_log common

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io             [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket     [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]

ProxyPass        /socket.io http://localhost:3000/socket.io
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://localhost:3000/socket.io

</VirtualHost>
```

Now everything worked fine including my websocket connection.

Here is how i connected from the client (react-native) application.

```
    useEffect(() => {
            socketRef.current = io('https://messenger.example.com', { 
                query: {token},
                transports: ['websocket'],
              }
            )
    
            socketRef.current.on("connect", () => {
              console.log('Connection successful');
            });
            
           ...

        })
```